# how to call outlook using Administrator account not email sender account

Tags: python, outlook, task, schedule

I created a task schedule to daily run my python script(it will call my outlook to send email to others.), but i found outlook cannot be called if i select 'Run whether user is logged on or not'. Because the PC run this task schedule will be restarted sometimes by others, then this task schedule cannot run if i forget to re-login to this PC.

Anyone know how to resolve my problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the Administrator as account.
2. Select "Run whether user is loggoed on or not".
3. Select the "Run with highest privileges" to test it.

Comment: This is what i did and the task will hang on calling outlook to send email.